# PartialView() does not return a View with a underscore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

TemplateController:

this works:

```
 return PartialView("_Create");
```

but this does not work:

```
return PartialView();
```

The asp.net mvc convention should actually check a View folder with the name of the controller => "Template" and check for a View the same name as the action  => "Create".

This is valid for a return View(). Why does a return PartialView() not just consider the underscore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is specifically for ASP.NET MVC5. It may require slight modification to work with other version of MVC but it should generally be applicable.

To have `return Partial(model)` respect underscores on partial names, you need a custom view engine. Fortunately this is an exceedingly trivial custom view engine.

```
public class CustomRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomRazorViewEngine()
    {
      var underScored = new[] { "~/Views/{1}/_{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/{1}/_{0}.vbhtml" }

      PartialViewLocationFormats = underScored.Union(PartialViewLocationFormats).ToArray();
    }
}
```

The following format is the default patterns for Shared views:

```
~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml
```

You could include alternates for these too if you wish. If you specifically want to only serve files with the underscore, remove the union and merely use: `PartialViewLocationFormats = underScored;`

This is with the razor view engine, I assume it would be comparable with the webforms view engine if that's your engine of choice.

Lastly you need to register this to be the view engine:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //View Engines
        ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(ViewEngines.Engines.Single(x => x is RazorViewEngine));
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorViewEngine());
```

The `Startup` class is specific to MVC5, this would vary slightly between versions. You could use App_Start files with webactivator or the global.asax in other versions.

Answer (score 3):

It is only a naming convention that partial views should start with underscore.
but strangely /mvc engine doesn't search for partial views with underscore.

1. so you have to explicitly say `return PartialView("_Create")`.
   or
2. Break the naming convention so that u don't have strings lying in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on this across the web, opinions are very divided as to why the _ should be there / if it should be there at all.

I would argue that **this is not a asp.net mvc naming convention**, and the proof is that the framework itself doesn't adhere to this. (as you pointed out in your question)

The origin of the _ comes from webmatrix/asp.net where _ is used for resources that aren't directly servable to the user.

The only thing that **could** be prefixed are views that are reusable components such as _layout, and maybe a _nav or _datepicker

Razor kind of removed the concept of a partial views anyway (as there is no difference similar to the one between **.aspx** and **.ascx,** in razor it's all **.cshtml** anyway).

Comment: if you use "_Foo.cshtml" and just return PartialView(mydata); it doesn't find it if your action calls the Foo() method in the controller. But by using return PartialView("_Foo", mydata); it can find it.